# How to inflate/deflate `Path` in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, canvas, path

I need to inflate or deflate the canvas path of freeform? Does somebody know how to do this? I.e. I need similar [inflate](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Rect/inflate.html) or [deflate](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Rect/deflate.html) methods which are exist for `Rect` class.

[image]

Comment: [offsetCurve](https://pub.dev/documentation/bezier/latest/bezier/Bezier/offsetCurve.html) - this explains what it does: https://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/#offsetting

Comment: @pskink I am not sure how it can helps. Freeform means all - lines, arcs, ovals etc. If path is correct square so why bezier curves here?

Comment: ok so you want to **inflate** or to **scale**? honestly I don't know how you want to inflate a line for example, maybe post two images: before and after inflating

Comment: @pskink inflate means `moving edges outwards by the given delta`, deflate means `moving edges inwards by the given delta`

Comment: so there is no such thing in flutter `Path` API, the nearest thing is [transform](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Path/transform.html) method that only lets you scale your `Path`

Comment: @pskink I tried the method `transform` and `Matrix4..scale()` but it scaled the path and **also shifts it**. Don't you know why is that?
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/137524

Comment: see the last code snippet at the bottom of https://stackoverflow.com/a/77375318/2252830 and replace `rotateZ` with `scale` (or use `composeMatrixFromOffsets` directly with `anchor` set to the same value as `translate`)

Comment: @pskink it seems I didn't catch the idea. I **do not know** which values I need to use for `translate`.

Comment: the "center point"  of your `Path` - if you don't know it from the "path definition" you can get some approximation with `Path.getBounds` method (or similar - I don't have the docs right now) which returns a bounding rect and then get `.center` property on it

Comment: @pskink I've got it. I know my center point. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The answer is inspired by [@pskink](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2252830/pskink) comments in the original question. As Fluttter canvas API does not contain the functionality to deflate/inflate path of any form the only way to do that is using the method `Path.transform` with centered tranformation:

```dart
final originalPath = Path();
final originalPathCenter = Offset(..., ...);
final deflatedPath = originalPath.transform(_getScalingMatrix(0.995, originalPathCenter));
final inflatedPath = originalPath.transform(_getScalingMatrix(1.001, originalPathCenter));

Float64List _getScalingMatrix(double scale, [Offset center = Offset.zero]) {
  assert(scale >= 0);
  return (Matrix4.identity()
          ..translate(center.dx, center.dy)
          ..scale(scale)
          ..translate(-center.dx, -center.dy))
        .storage;
}
```